# How should the Request Body look like?

Tags: wcf, json, request, fiddler

I have a WCF service with a method which looks like this (returns null for testing with the debugger, I care only about getting data in for now):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "fares", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public List<Fare> GetFares(Dictionary<int, int> itineraries, decimal? threshold, bool includeInternational)
{
    return null;
}
```

I am trying to make a request to that method using Fiddler, but can't get my head around on what the correct Request Body should be. I could change the Dictionary parameter to something else if that works better.

In Request Headers I pass:

> User-Agent: Fiddler
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

What should I put in the body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

```
{
"itineraries" : [{"Key":1,"Value":2},{"Key":2,"Value":3}],
"threshold" : 1.0,
"includeInternational" : true
}
```

The dictionary serializes as a Key Value array.

Comment: I explicitly set this as POST request in Fiddler, so the data is not sent as part of the URI. The problem is that in Fiddler I want to type the data manually and have no idea how it has to look, so I end up with server side exceptions.

Comment: Sorry i missread the question and updated my answe. i think the above json is what you are after. If you still get an exception turn system.diagnostics on in the web config if you havent already.